# Can't find heroku JAWSDB host

Tags: mysql, heroku, mysql-workbench

I'm looking to connect my JAWSDB to my local mysql client. On the JAWSDB docs on Heroku we get this breakdown of the database url:

```
mysql://user:pass@instance:port/default_schema
```

This is how my database url is formatted. My mysql client (MYSQL Workbench) is asking for a 'host'. What part of the url do I put here? Or where can I find this information?

Comment: `instance` is the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out 'instance' in the URL is the host.

Answer (score 3):

Your Host in this case will be "instance". It will be a long string that starts after the "@" symbol and ends before the ":"

My Host looks somthing like this...
`enqxqx10c2f7hv2e.cbetxd3yhwsb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com`

I pulled it from this connection string...
mysql://kjygfmf3pfg4q148:kshfm2g4aflfy2a9@**enqxqx10c2f7hv2e.cbetxd3yhwsb.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com**:3306/xmvmgh118drq2x10

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As Tommy pointed out, the **instance** referenced in the documentation is the hostname of the server. We have updated our docs to be more explicit about this.